LangChain RetrievalQA Working Locally but Failing on Windows Server Deployment
I'm using LangChain (version langchain==0.3.3) and specifically the RetrievalQA class from langchain.chains to retrieve answers from PDF files. My setup works perfectly on my local machine, but I’m having trouble getting it to work after deploying it to a live server running Django on a Windows Server.
Here’s the core part of my code:
conversation_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(

llm=llm,

retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 30}),

# memory=memory,

chain_type="stuff",

chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": my_prompt},

)

response = conversation_chain.invoke(

{"query": fieldPrompt.Prompt}

)

In my local environment, everything runs smoothly. However, once deployed, it doesn’t work as expected, and I’m not getting the intended responses.
Could anyone help me figure out why this might be happening on the live server? Is there something specific about deploying on Windows Server or Django that might cause issues with LangChain or RetrievalQA? Any troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
conversation_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(

llm=llm,

retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 30}),

# memory=memory,

chain_type="stuff",

chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": my_prompt},

)

response = conversation_chain.invoke(

{"query": fieldPrompt.Prompt}

)


What llm are you using? Is the windows server authorized to use that resource? Also can you share error logs from running the Django application, if it doesn't work there should be some output
